# Hibernate Envers get revisions for criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

Using Hibernate Envers (4.1.9.Final). Trying to get all the revisions (date, revision number) for which a entities have changed of a certain type and that match a certain criterion.

This is the code that I'm currently having:

```
    AuditReader auditReader = AuditReaderFactory.get(entityManager);
    AuditQuery query = auditReader.createQuery()
            .forRevisionsOfEntity(InventoryItem.class, false, true)
            .add(AuditEntity.property("section_uuid").eq(sectionUuid))
            .addOrder(AuditEntity.revisionNumber().desc());
    List<Object[]> revisions = query.getResultList();
```

1. This returns one element for each changed `InventoryItem`. So, if two `InventoryItem`s were changed in a revision, I get two elements -- I do not want that.
2. This returns also the actual `InventoryItem`s, I think that's a bit heavy -- I do not want that.

How can I get a distinct collection of revisions (date, revision number)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the `addProjection` method on `AuditQuery`. You can add a projection on the revision number and date.

Comment: I think you're absolutely right. I played a bit with *projections* but didn't quite get it to work. It must have been too late, too tired, because with your fresh motivation I had it working pretty quickly.

Answer (score 6):

On basis of Adam's answer, here is the code that I implemented. I'll mark his answer as the accepted answer.

```
AuditReader auditReader = AuditReaderFactory.get(entityManager);
AuditQuery query = auditReader.createQuery()
    .forRevisionsOfEntity(InventoryItem.class, false, true)
    .addProjection(AuditEntity.revisionNumber().distinct())
    .addProjection(AuditEntity.revisionProperty("created"))
    .add(AuditEntity.property("section_uuid").eq(sectionUuid))
    .addOrder(AuditEntity.revisionNumber().desc());
```

As a result, `query.getResultList()` will return a collection of `Object[]`, where each `Object[]` contains:

- `Object[0]`: revision number as `int`
- `Object[1]`: revision date as `java.util.Date`, corresponding the `created` `revisionProperty`