# Mapping to an older revision of an entity with JPA annotations

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-envers

I recently found out about envers for auditing and have been able to use it successfully to track revisions and fetch them using the `@Audited` annotation and the `AuditReader`. Now, what I'm trying to achieve is retaining the mappings to an audited entity at the revision they were made instead of the newest revision.

Quick example:

Let's say I have a recipe for cookies which I use to make batches of cookies (pseudo classes for classes below). Each recipe has a list of instructions to follow and doing so creates a batch:

```
@Audited
@Table(name="recipes")
class CookieRecipe {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="recipe")
    private List<RecipeStep> steps;

    private void addStep(String instruction) {
        steps.add(new RecipeStep(instruction));
    }
}

@Table(name="batches")
class CookieBatch {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(...)
    private CookieRecipe recipe;
}

@Audited
@Table(name="recipe_step")
class RecipeStep {

    @Column
    private String instruction;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(...)
    private CookieRecipe recipe;

    private RecipeStep(String instruction) {
        this.instruction = instruction;
    }
}
```

Now, let's say I have this Cookie Recipe:

```
CookieRecipe recipe = new CookieRecipe();
recipe.addStep("Make the dough");
recipe.addStep("Place on pan");
recipe.addStep("Bake at 400F for 20 minutes");
entityManager.persist(recipe);
```

And I'll be using this recipe to create my first batch of cookies:

```
CookieBatch batch = new CookieBatch(recipe);
entityManager.persist(batch);
```

If I wanted to change the recipe to say, for example, 375F instead of 400F, this creates revision 2 of the `CookieRecipe`, which is what I expect and want. However, I want the batch I already created to point to revision 1 of the `CookieRecipe`. Currently, if I fetch the `CookieBatch` I've already created using its ID, the reference to the `CookieRecipe` ends up being the latest revision (the one with 375F).

Is this something I can accomplish using envers?

Comment: `CookieBatch` not being `@Audited` is intentional? If so, I don't believe there's an elegant way of doing what you're trying to do.

Comment: @SergeiBednar Yes, only reason being that once a `CookieBatch` is completed, it does not change. So I figured it was unnecessary as it would just create an audit table that would never really be used... unless I misunderstood this behavior. I'm not opposed to adding `@Audited` to it if it leads to the solution.

Comment: I think your only other solution here is to keep a `recipeId` and a `recipeRevisionNumber` values, change the `recipe` entity in your `CookieBatch` to `@Transient`, and handle the querying of the recipe yourself, via envers `AuditCriteria`, after you load the `CookieBatch` entity.

Comment: @SergeiBednar I think this will be the solution that works for me, mind posting it as a solution? Further, do you have insight on how to get the `recipeRevisionNumber` at the time of persisting the `CookieBatch`?

Comment: The `CookieRecipe` should be persisted by this point, and you can get the latest revision via an audit criteria. Check out this documentation, it's pretty solid: http://docs.jboss.org/envers/docs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your only way of doing this is keeping `recipeId`, `recipeRevisionNumber` fields in your `CookieBatch`, and loading a `CookieRecipe` object yourself.

```
@Table(name="batches")
class CookieBatch {

    @Column(...)
    Long recipeId;

    @Column(...)
    Long recipeRevisionNumber;

    @Transient
    private CookieRecipe recipe;

    @PostLoad
    public void loadRecipe()
    {
        // Load a cookie recipe via audit criteria
    }
}
```

audit criteria is pretty self explanatory, check out this example:

[Hibernate Envers get revisions for criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25542231/hibernate-envers-get-revisions-for-criteria)

and a documentation for all things envers:

http://docs.jboss.org/envers/docs/

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that `CookieBatch` be audited as well as maintain a bidirectional relationship between `CookieBatch` and `CookieRecipe`.  This way, Envers can query the appropriate versions from either side correctly.

In other words, add the following to `CookieRecipe`

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "recipe", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<CookieRecipeBatch> batches = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then you can fetch the appropriate versioned data using the following loop:

```
AuditReader reader = AuditReaderFactory.get( session );
for ( Number revision : reader.getRevisions(CookieRecipe.class, recipeId ) ) {
  CookieRecipe recipe = reader.find( CookieRecipe.class, recipeId, revision );
  // recipe.getSteps() - contains all steps with revision number <= revision
  // recipe.getBatches() - contains all batches with revision number <= revision
}
```

The above should give you a `CookieRecipe` at a specific revision with the appropriate batch and step snapshots.

Comment: My goal is to fetch a `CookieBatch` using the batch ID, and have it refer to the revision of the `CookieRecipe` used at the time of creation. I unfortunately don't have knowledge of what the 'appropriate revision' is, that's the missing data. Unless I specifically have to retrieve and store that when creating the `CookieBatch`, like what @SergeiBednar is recommending?