# Audited OneToOne Mapping to Envers Revision using Postload in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, kotlin, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-envers

I'm currently trying to implement a version system in my Spring Boot application.

The Customer submits an Order with a Product that is worth 300$ -> now if my client changes the price of the product order to 350$ the old order should still show 300$.

After some research I thought Hibernate Envers was fit to my use case.

I tried to use this example [Mapping to an older revision of an entity with JPA annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39884182/8585553)

It should be straightforward. On creation of the Order I save the productId and the current revision of the product.
Then everytime postload I get the appropriate revision using the hibernate auditreader.

```
@PersistenceContext
val entityManager: EntityManager? = null;
@Autowired
val sessionFactory: SessionFactory? = null
@Entity
@Table(name="ORDER_TABLE")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
class Order(
    var productId:Int?,
    var productRevision: Int?,
    @OneToOne
    var product: Product
) : BaseEntity() {

    @PostLoad
    fun loadProduct() {
        // val auditReader = AuditReaderFactory.get(entityManager)
        val auditReader = AuditReaderFactory.get(sessionFactory?.currentSession)
        val query = auditReader.createQuery()
            .forEntitiesAtRevision(Product::class.java, product.id)
            .add(AuditEntity.id().eq(id))
        product = query.singleResult as Product
    }
}`
```

I can't get it working because I can't get the entityManager or the Hibernate Session inside the Jpa Entity

Is this possible for my use case or should I look at something different.

Answer (score 1):

If you are saving orders, auditing is a bad way to manage this. The price should be per order position and is an inherent part of the domain. The price is usually copied over or in case of a discount, sometimes even changed on a case by case basis. IMO you should model this explicitly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 

I know created another entity named OrderProduct which closely resembles Product and create a new entry for each seperate Order. Is this a better approach?
`
 fun createOrder(order: Order) {
        order.orderProduct.id = null
        order.orderProduct = orderProductRepository.save(order.orderProduct)
        orderRepository.save(order)
 }
`
I tried to find a way to save a snapshot of the whole Entity with all relationships also "snapshotted" to have a immutable copy of all information. Now if the category changes I need to repeat the whole process.

Comment: That approach is IMO better because that information usually should be immutable. Only copy the data that you need to be immutable. It's your system, so you have to know if you need to copy the category association in order to make sense of an order.